# How to extract array of array values and push in same array in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have this array of array

```
a1 = ['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']];
```

how to get this 'three' and 'four' out of child array and push it in parent array as string like below

```
a2 = ['one', 'two', 'three, four'];
```

like this. can I solve it with ES6?

Note: with space between 'three' and 'four' as shown in a2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and conditionally [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the subarray's values:

```js
const a1 = ['one', 'two', ['three', 'four']];
const a2 = a1.map(v => Array.isArray(v) ? v.join(', ') : v);

console.log(a2);
```